# Reading the contents of a NFC Tag

Tags: android, tags, nfc

I am trying to read an NFC Tag on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus S.

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String nachricht = "";
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = getIntent()
                .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            NdefMessage[] msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                nachricht = nachricht + " " + msgs;
            }

            Log.e("WriteTagApp", nachricht );
        }
    }

}
```

With Log.e("WriteTagApp", nachricht ); my app writes the message of the tag into the Debugger. 
It looks something like this: [Landroid.nfc.NdefMessage;@4184ce18

I dont seem to be able to understand what is going on here and how to get the actual content of the message.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NDefMessage isn't a String, it's an object.  By concatonating it you're just adding the output of its "toString" method.  Instead, you need to look at the [NdefRecords](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html) inside the NdefMessage and pull the data from the payload field in there.

Comment: Ah thanks.
Added an EditText Field, where I enter the payload    
`mNote.setText(new String(messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload()));`
      
This way you can read the first Record of the Tag where the Text is.